How to parse answer ( content ) from openai response to markdown format?
I have a Next.js action that uses OpenAI to generate an answer :
export async function continueConversation(
  messages: CoreMessage[],
  data: PersonResponse,
  prompt: string
) {
  const { full_name, job_title, ...rest } = data
  const result = await streamText({
    system: `You are a ${job_title} and your name is ${full_name}. Answer the questions based on ${JSON.stringify(
      rest
    )}`,
    model: openai("gpt-4o-2024-05-13"),
    messages,
    prompt,
  })

  const stream = createStreamableValue(result.textStream)
  return stream.value
}


In the UI, I have this part of code:
{messages.map((m, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="whitespace-pre-wrap flex flex-col px-8">
                <div
                  className={cn(
                    "flex items-start",
                    m.role === "user" && "justify-end"
                  )}
                >
                  {m.role === "assistant" && (
                    <Avatar className="w-8 h-8 mr-3 mt-1">
                      <AvatarImage
                        src={`https://${github_url}.png`}
                        alt={getInitials(full_name as string)}
                      />
                      <AvatarFallback className="text-sm font-semibold tracking-[2px] bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffaa40] via-[#9c40ff] to-[#ffaa40]">
                        {getInitials(full_name as string)}
                      </AvatarFallback>
                    </Avatar>
                  )}
                  <span
                    className={cn(
                      "my-2",
                      m.role === "user" &&
                        "bg-neutral-800 px-4 py-3 rounded-full"
                    )}
                  >
                    {m.content as string}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}


In the output, I get the result as Markdown:


Just include in the prompt instructions for the output format that you would like.

You can use react-markdown package to display the markdown and the package size is only 45.4kb
npm install react-markdown
import Markdown from "react-markdown"

export default function Home(){
  // api calls here

  return (
   {messages.map((m, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="whitespace-pre-wrap flex flex-col px-8">
           <div>
             {m.role === "assistant" && (
              <Avatar >
                <AvatarImage
                  src={`https://${github_url}.png`}
                  alt={getInitials(full_name as string)}
                />
               <AvatarFallback className="text-sm">
                {getInitials(full_name as string)}
               </AvatarFallback>
             </Avatar>
             )}
             <span
              className={cn(
               "my-2",
              m.role === "user" &&
              "bg-neutral-800 px-4 py-3 rounded-full"
            )}
            >
              <Markdown>{m.content}</Markdown>
          </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   ))}
  )
}

